# Excel VBA Macros: Find/Match cells from one sheet to a column in another

Tags: vba, excel

Ok, so I have a workbook with multiple sheets.  The Worksheets are named:

Inputs
Outputs
Hardware

Input and output are serial IDs matched to actualy IP Addresses.
Input 1 : 192.168.0.1
input 2 : 192.168.0.2
... etc

Hardware has 3 columns.  The first has Devices, 2nd column which has the Input Serial IDs and the 3rd of Output Serial IDs.

Toaster : Input 1 : Output 3
Blender : Input 2 : Output 2
...etc

Now, normally, I'd be using Vlookup(A1,Inputs!A:B,2) and Vlookup(A1,Outputs!A:B,2), but I have to incorporate this into the VBA macro we have and I have no idea how.

```
Sub TrackHardware()

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'Activating Device
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
currentOutputRow = 2
Dim test As String


For currentRow = 2 To 32768 'The last row of your data
'For Loop to go through contents of Hardware individually

    If Not (IsEmpty(Worksheets("Hardware").Range("A" & currentRow).Value)) Then
        'To Skip the empty cells 

            HWID=Worksheets("Hardware").Range("a" & currentvalue).Value
            'HWID is the search term coming from Sheet:'Hardware'

            Desc=Worksheets("Hardware").Range("D" & currentvalue).Value
            'Desc is the Plain Text description coming from Sheet:'Hardware'



            inputrow={Match pseudocode that didn't work(HWID, "Inputs", Range:= "A:B", 2) }
            outputrow={Match pseudocode that didn't work(HWID, "Outputs", Range:= "A:B", 2) }
            'trying to find the row # of search term in Sheets 'Input' and 'Output'

            Worksheets("Inputs").Range("C" & inputrow).Value = Desc
            Worksheets("Outputs").Range("C" & outputrow).Value = Desc
             'Pastes The Device Description to Input and Output Sheets



    End If
Next currentRow
'And on to the next line in 'Hardware'

End Sub
```

I'd also like to account for Errors like 2 devices on the same Input/Output or a Blank cell, but I think I can figure those out myself.  This Find function is what's really giving me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there seems to be a problem if you are not able to call on the `Application.Match` function.  I am not sure why that would be missing, but I know there are some "limited" versions of Office/Excel which do not have full VBA functionality. I am not sure if that is the case with your installation.

Now, on to your problem though...

**To use the `Application.Match` function:**

The `Match` function takes a single row or single column range input. You are attempting to pass in the range `"A:B"`, which will always raise an error.  Change to a single row/column range instead.

Further, `2` is not an option for the third argument, which can be either -1 (less than), 0 or False (exact), or 1 (greater than). I'm not sure this alone will raise an error, but you should fix it anyways.

```
inputRow = Application.Match(HWID, Worksheets("Inputs").Range("A:A"), False)
```

If an exact match cannot be found, it will raise an error, which you can trap like so:

```
inputRow = Application.Match(HWID, Worksheets("Inputs").Range("A:A"), False)
If IsError(inputRow) Then
    'Do something like:
    MsgBox HWID & " not found!", vbInformation
    Exit Sub
End If
```

**NOTE** If you actually need to check *both* columns, then you can either double up on the `Match` function, or use the range `.Find` method instead.

```
Dim foundRange as Range
Set foundRange = Range("A:B").Find(HWID)
If Not foundRange Is Nothing Then
    inputRow = foundRange.Row
Else
    MsgBox HWID & " not found!", vbInformation
End If
```

**Handling errors with `WorksheetFunction.Match`**

Error trapping for `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` should be something like:

```
inputRow = Empty
On Error Resume Next
inputRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(HWID, Worksheets("Inputs").Range("A:A"), False)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Match not found", vbInformation
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: So I tried the "inputrow=Application.Match(###)" and it throws a 1004 error.  I then Typed "Application.Ma" and right clicked to "List Properties/Methods" and Match isn't on there. Typing M-A-T resulted in "MathCoProcessor"...

I'm running Visual Basic 7.1 and the Excel Version is Excel Business 2013 if that helps.

Comment: Nevermind, I found it!  Proper usage was" Application.WorksheetFunctions.Match(HWID,Worksheets("Inputs").Range("A:B),2) "

Comment: You could try `Application.Worksheetfunction.Match (###)` but that will require slightly different error trapping since that function will raise errors rather than return an error value. Try that and let me know how it goes. I'm on my phone right now but I can update my answer with the error handling when I'm in the office later.

Comment: Application.Match should also work though,  I'm not sure why it won't work for you unless maybe that is a version of Excel which does not come with the full set of VBA functionality...

Comment: Application.Worksheetfunction works, but it pops the 1004 Error when the search value doesn't exist within the range... and goes around error trapping.

I'm looking into why I don't have Application.Match.

Comment: OK now that I take a closer look at this there are a few problems in your implementation. I will revise my answer to fix them but would like to discuss.  What do you intend the `2` to do in the Match function?

Comment: Application.Match is working now.  The issue was that "inputrow" was called as a Integer datatype.  I set it as a Variant so now, it can take the Errors being thrown... it still doesn't show up as a method, nor in the MSDN references.
THANKS!

Comment: I use it so often I forgot it doesn't show up as available method in the intellisense.  But yes, because that function can return an Error value, you need to `Dim inputRow as Variant` otherwise you'll get a mismatch I think.